# Perl script to remap printers from one print server to another

Tags: perl, windows-server-2003

My Perl script needs altering to allow for long printer share names. This script works fine for short printer share names. If you do a NET SHARE, you will see what I mean.. Anyway, here is the Perl script:

```
#this script will not migrate novaPDF pritter
my @printers;
my %PQ2;
my %PQ;
my @NewPQ;
my $NewServer = "MTAPQ10";
my $OldServer = "MTAPQ5";

#Retrive print queues info from the new network print server
print "Generating a printer list on $NewServer..\n";
@NewPQ = `net view $NewServer`;


#Create a required TEMP folder on C:
system("md C:\\TEMP") if(not (-e "C:\\TEMP"));

#Create a VBScripts to enumerate network printer connections
open(OUTFILE,">C:\\TEMP\\EnumPQ.vbs") or die "Unable to create TEMP file";

print OUTFILE  "Option Explicit\n";
print OUTFILE  "Dim objNetwork, objPrinter, intDrive, intNetLetter\n";
print OUTFILE  "Set objNetwork = CreateObject(\"WScript\.Network\")\n";
print OUTFILE  "Set objPrinter = objNetwork.EnumPrinterConnections\n";
print OUTFILE  "For intDrive = 0 To (objPrinter.Count -1) Step 2\n";
print OUTFILE  "  intNetLetter = IntNetLetter +1\n";
print OUTFILE  "  Wscript.Echo objPrinter.Item(intDrive +1)\n";
print OUTFILE  "Next\n";
print OUTFILE  "Wscript\.Quit(1)\n";

close OUTFILE;

#Run VBScript EnumPQ.vbs to generate a list of connected network printers
print "Enumerating local printers...\n";
my @results = `cscript c:\\TEMP\\EnumPQ.vbs`;
print "Local printer enumeration complete\n";

my $FOUND = 0;
#Search for printer(s) on MTAPQ5
foreach my $rec (@results)
{
    chomp $rec;

    next if($rec =~ /nova/i); #bypass nova PDF printer
    #Searching for old server in the form of \\ServerName
    if($rec =~ /\\\\$OldServer/i)
    {
        #Exp rec=\\MTAPQ2\(05-103) HP Color LaserJet 4650 PS 6=
        push @printers, $rec;
        $FOUND = 1;
    }
}

if($FOUND)
{
    &RemovePrinter();
    &AddPrinter();
}
else
{
    print "No network printer on $OldServer found..\n"
}

exit 0; #exit main
#===============================================================================
#Creat a VB script to remove network printer(s)
#===============================================================================
sub RemovePrinter
{

open(OUTFILE,">C:\\TEMP\\rmprint.vbs") or die "Error open outfile..";
print OUTFILE 'Set WshNetwork = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Network")'."\n\n";

foreach my $printer (@printers)
{
    $printer =~ m/^\\\\$OldServer\\\((.+)\)/i;
    $PQ2{$1} = "old printer";
}

foreach my $shrname (@NewPQ)
{
    chomp $shrname;
    $shrname =~ m/^.+\((.+)\).+/i;
    $PQ{$1} = "New printer";
}

my @PQ2Printers = keys %PQ2;

foreach my $prt (@PQ2Printers)
{
    if(exists $PQ{$prt})
    {
        #Create VB Script to remove the found printers
        print OUTFILE "PrinterPath = \"\\\\$OldServer\\$prt\"\n";
        print OUTFILE "WshNetwork.RemovePrinterConnection PrinterPath, true, true\n\n";
    }
}


print OUTFILE  "Wscript\.Quit(1)\n";
close OUTFILE;

print "Deleting $OldServer printer(s)..\n";
sleep 2;
my $rm_results = `cscript c:\\TEMP\\rmprint.vbs`;
#print "remove result:\n";
#print $rm_results."\n";


}#end sub RemovePrinter
#===============================================================================
#Create a VB script to add network printers
#===============================================================================
sub AddPrinter
{
open(OUTFILE,">C:\\TEMP\\addprint.vbs") or die "Error open outfile..";
print OUTFILE 'Set WshNetwork = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Network")'."\n\n";


my @PQ2Printers = keys %PQ2;

#if old printer exists on new server, map it.
foreach my $prt (@PQ2Printers)
{
        if(exists $PQ{$prt})
        {
        #Create VB Script to map the found printers to new server
        print OUTFILE "PrinterPath = \"\\\\$NewServer\\$prt\"\n";
        print OUTFILE "WshNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection PrinterPath, true, true\n\n";
        print "Remapping $OldServer printer to: \\\\$NewServer\\$prt\n";
    }
}

print OUTFILE  "Wscript\.Quit(1)\n";
close OUTFILE;

sleep 2;
my $add_results = `cscript c:\\TEMP\\addprint.vbs`;
#print "Add result:\n";
#print $add_results."\n";

}#end sub AddPrinter
#===============================================================================
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is a perl question, seems like the issue is how to get wide output from `net view` or how to query the printer list with windows scripting. You may get better answers if you strip down the code to the minimum necessary to show the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked into the various Win32 modules at CPAN?

These provide much better interfaces than trying to pull things off the Windows command line.

For example [Win32::Printer::Enum](http://search.cpan.org/~wasx/Win32-Printer-0.9.1/Printer/Enum.pm) will find and list all available printers instead of using:

```
 @NewPQ = `net view $NewServer`;
```

And, you should be able to use Perl's `mkdir` command instead of going off into a system command to make a directory.

If you have downloaded ActivePerl, take a look at their Win32 modules. It probably has everything you need.